# Confusions about proof regarding proper maps

Tags: general-topology, compactness, closed-map

I am currently trying to prove  that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed continuous map between topological spaces such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact for all $y\in Y$ then f is proper. In this sense $f$ is proper if for every compact set $K\subset Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $X$.

I am really quite lost on this one as I feel like I don't know enough about $X$ or $Y$ to really do anything. In previous problems/proofs I was working on like this I usually had that $Y$ or $X$ was locally compact or Hausdorff.

Since I didn't really know what I should do, I tried writing the pre image $f^{-1}(K)$ as:

$$f^{-1}(K)=\bigcup_{y\in K}f^{-1}(y)$$

However this doesn't really seem useful as an infinite collection of compact sets needn't be compact. I suspect continuity or the closedeness of $f$ could help but I can't see how. Any hints to get me going in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f: X \to Y$ is closed iff

> For all $y \in Y$, if $O \subseteq X$ is open such that $f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subseteq O$, there exists some open $y \in U \subseteq Y$, so that $f^{-1}[U] \subseteq O$.

A sort of "reverse continuity" characteristic of closed maps. The proof is not hard. (We only need the left to right implication as a lemma).

From this: let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $f^{-1}[K]$ with $K$ compact. Use the "lemma" to define a new cover of $K$ based on $\mathcal{U}$...

Comment: How do I define a new cover of $K$ based on $\mathcal{U}$? If $\mathcal{U}$ is just a random collection of open sets in $X$ that happens to cover $f^{-1}(K)$ then how can I know anything about whether any of those open sets contain any $f^{-1}(y)$ or $f^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is an open nbd of $y$.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. For every $y \in K$, $f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subseteq f^{-1}[K]$ and so is covered by finitely many $U \in \mathcal{U}$. Use their union in the lemma.

Comment: I don’t follow what you say here

Comment: Isn’t what u wrote true for any map between top spaces? Like $f^{-1}(y)\subset f^{-1}(K)$ is true for every map if $y\in K$ so I don’t see how that helps us

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. You have an open cover of the compact set $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$. What can you say now?

Comment: I’m confused how’d I get an open cover for $f^{-1}(y)$? I got an open cover for $f^{-1}(K)$ which I was then able to make finite using the lemma and the fact that $K$ compact

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. The cover for $f^{-1}[K]$ isn’t finite and the lemma doesn’t apply to it. For fixed $y\in K$ we know that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is compact by assumption. It’s covered by $\mathcal{U}$ as the larger set $f^{-1}[K]$ is. So…..

Comment: @Hennon Brandsma if $K$ compact then there’s a finite cover of open set $U_i$.  $f$ is continuous so the pre image of open sets needs to be open, thus we have a finite cover of $f^{-1}(K)$ given by $f(U_i)$ for each $U_i$. That’s what I meant when I said I had a finite cover for $f^{-1}(K)$. I see that each $f^{-1}(y)$ has a finite cover and that it’s also covered by $\mathcal{U}$ but  I can’t see what that says about $f^{-1}(K)$

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. That’s nonsense. The $U$ sets live in $X$ so they *have* no preimage and their images aren’t open. So that’s bullocks.

Comment: sorry my notation is getting ahead of me. $K$ is compact so every cover has a countable sub cover of open sets $Y_i\in Y$ then the rest follows to give a countable cover of $f^{-1}(K)$, but this is useless I think since it doesn’t show that every cover of $f^{-1}(K)$ has a finite sub cover. 

I’m really trying to see where you’re trying to get me go with this but I can’t see how to construct a finite cover of $f^{-1}(K)$
 using this lemma

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. My hints are very clear and complete solutions abound on this site. Do some thinking. You only have one cover to work with to find a finite subcover of. The lemma says to look for open neighbourhoods of the fibres etc.